# mount lifecycle hook not triggered in Vue js 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am new to Vue and was struggling with this basic code in Vue js 2.
I want to call a function on load of the component. So i am using mounted life cycle hook. But that is not getting triggered.

```
<template>
    <div>--- {{ res }} ---</div>
</template>

 <script>
    export default {
      name: "OrderChargeDetailsContainer",
      data() {
        return {          
          res: "It should change",
        };
      },
        
      mounted() {
        alert('alert');     
        this.res = "Updated data";   
      },
    };
 </script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you see any error on console?

Answer (score 2):

It should work as mentioned in the following running code :

```js
new Vue({
el:"#app",
  name: "OrderChargeDetailsContainer",
  data() {
    return {
      res: "It should change",
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    alert('alert');
    this.res = "Updated data";
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>--- {{ res }} ---</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working here. But for some reason, only the "created" hook is working in my application. Thanks for quick response